# How to remain check status of <s:checkboxlist> tag

Tags: jsp, struts2

In struts2, Is there any way to remain  status when return the Jsp after validation failed?
My Jsp:

```
<div>
    <s:checkboxlist name="suppresses"
list="#{'1':'ACCESS','2':'TradeNet','3':'Parcel','4':'Air Bunker'}">
    </s:checkboxlist>
</div>
```

Action:

```
   private int[] suppresses;
```

when I return the page after validation failed, how to remain checkstatus?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Hi, you see these 4 checkbox, I want to know how to check No1 and No2 for e.g. when page loading,

Comment: On page loading and after validation fail is different cases. Which one do you want?

Comment: @AleksandrM can I say both? or anyone you know, please tell me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution myself, share with others
only need change the Array to List

```
private List<String> suppresses;
```

then the checkboxlist will be checked depends on the list values

Comment: That isn't the only change you've made.